# mysql query to arrange data from four tables according to timestamp

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get data from four tables with respect to the the "type". Types can be comment, cover pic change, friend request accept etc. but the problem is the query i made is not working by repeating the types for all and timestamp for all. the query i made is

```
SELECT c.up_date, c.user_id, c.id, f.id,
       f.up_date, f.friend1, f.friend2, f.status,
       s.postdate, s.status, s.id, s.display_name, s.userid, s.userid1, s.type,
       c.type, f.type
FROM cover_pic c, wp_userstatus s, wp_friends f
WHERE s.userid = f.friend1
AND s.userid = c.user_id
AND f.status =3
AND c.user_id =4
ORDER BY s.postdate
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

can anyone help me with the right query with respect to timestamp and the type

here is the result its giving me

[image]

what i want

> timestamp userid_id id display_name type
>
> 233232323  1         1 paramveer    comment
>
> 1212121212 1        2  paramveer     coverpic

Comment: can add sample records with desired result?

Comment: sample records from all four tables?

Comment: First show the desired result. Maybe this is already sufficient.

Comment: okh let me take a screenshot and post it here 1min

Comment: please see i added the screenshot . it should arrange things according to types. its creating different column of types :(

Comment: can you post your desired output.?

Comment: Now we see what you get, but we need to know what you want.

Comment: desired output like a sample of it?

Comment: Yes, show how it should look like. Do you want different columns, different sorting order, something else?

Comment: In your question you talk about *four* tables, but I see only *three* tables in your query.

Comment: ok i tried making one example sorry for the bad formatting really tensed at the moment :(

Comment: its like i am trying to get activity of a user according to the timestamp and type of activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe* you want an `union` of joins

```
(select distinct s.postdate as postdate, s.userid, c.id, c.type
 from wp_userstatus s
 join cover_pic c on s.userid = c.user_id)
union
(select distinct s.postdate, s.userid, f.id, f.type
 from wp_userstatus s
 join wp_friends f on s.userid = f.friend1)
order by postdate
limit 30
```

It's really hard to tell.

Comment: still not working friend it has errors , still thanks for helping me

Comment: @ParamVeer Look at the fixed answer.

Comment: friend thank you for putting efforts but it giving the error `#1250 - Table 's' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause`

Comment: sorry friend again the same error `#1250 - Table 'wp_userstatus' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause`

Comment: I found an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3147496/1741542 and again learnt something in the course of answering ;-) Look at the modified answer. If it doesn't work, you might need to add an alias to the second select as well.

Comment: yes i have but still the results are incorrect the timestamp is being repeated 3 times

Comment: @ParamVeer When you have duplicate rows, you must add `distinct`.

Comment: its still repeating the timestamp i used distinct but then also is repeating it . m so tensed and i sorry to make u do so much. thanks for helping

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19686/discussion-between-olaf-dietsche-and-param-veer)